JavaScript module export not recognized using Webpack & Typescript
Problem
I have a function named index declared with export in a JavaScript file, when trying to use it I get an error message telling "does not provide an export named 'index'"
This is a long post as I will show all my files. I have tried to solve this for several days now without success, so that's why I show all of them. Probably I'm missing something essential but right now I'm out of ideas.
Tools

VsCode
Typescript
Webpack

Files & Folders

tsconfig.json
webpack.config.mjs
public/
src/
src/index.ts
src/index.hbs
site/favicon.ico

Typescript config
Defined in tsconfig.json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",
    "module": "ES6",
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noEmit": false,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "outDir": "./public",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "lib": [
        "DOM",
        "ES6"
    ],
    "typeRoots": [
        "node_modules/@types"
    ]
    },
    "include": ["src/**/*.ts"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}


Webpack config
My configuration for webpack looks like this
import CopyPlugin from 'copy-webpack-plugin';
import HtmlWebpackPlugin from 'html-webpack-plugin';
import path from 'path';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';


// Define __dirname
const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);

export default {
    entry: './src/index.ts',
    devtool: 'source-map',
    output: {
        filename: 'index.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: '/node_modules/',
            },
            {
                test: /\.sass$/i,
                use: ["style-loader","css-loader","sass-loader"],
            },            
        ],
    },
    mode: 'development', // or 'production',
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: 'WebX3',
            template: "src/index.hbs",
            favicon: 'site/favicon.ico',
        }),
    ],
    devServer: {
        static: './public',
    }
}


The source for index.html
Im using a custom template stored as index.hbs which ends up in public/index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title><%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="public">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
</body>

<script type="module">
    import { index } from './index.js';
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
        index('');
    });
</script>
</html>


My typescript source
The typescript source src/index.ts to create public/index.js
export function index(): void {
    console.log("Hello");
}


Running webpack
**npx webpack --config webpack.config.mjs**
asset favicon.ico 4.19 KiB [compared for emit]
asset index.js 1.81 KiB [compared for emit] (name: main) 1 related asset
asset index.html 503 bytes [compared for emit]
runtime modules 670 bytes 3 modules
./src/index.ts 54 bytes [built] [code generated]
webpack 5.92.1 compiled successfully in 1949 ms


Generated files in public/
-a----        2024-07-07     14:44           4286 favicon.ico
-a----        2024-07-07     14:56            503 index.html
-a----        2024-07-07     14:56           1851 index.js
-a----        2024-07-07     14:56           1402 index.js.map


Generated index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>WebX3</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="public">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico"><script defer src="index.js"></script></head>

<body>
</body>

<script type="module">
    import { index } from './index.js';
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
        index('');
    });
</script>
</html>


Generated index.js
/******/ (() => { // webpackBootstrap
/******/    "use strict";
/******/    // The require scope
/******/    var __webpack_require__ = {};
/******/    
/************************************************************************/
/******/    /* webpack/runtime/define property getters */
/******/    (() => {
/******/        // define getter functions for harmony exports
/******/        __webpack_require__.d = (exports, definition) => {
/******/            for(var key in definition) {
/******/                if(__webpack_require__.o(definition, key) && !__webpack_require__.o(exports, key)) {
/******/                    Object.defineProperty(exports, key, { enumerable: true, get: definition[key] });
/******/                }
/******/            }
/******/        };
/******/    })();
/******/    
/******/    /* webpack/runtime/hasOwnProperty shorthand */
/******/    (() => {
/******/        __webpack_require__.o = (obj, prop) => (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop))
/******/    })();
/******/    
/******/    /* webpack/runtime/make namespace object */
/******/    (() => {
/******/        // define __esModule on exports
/******/        __webpack_require__.r = (exports) => {
/******/            if(typeof Symbol !== 'undefined' && Symbol.toStringTag) {
/******/                Object.defineProperty(exports, Symbol.toStringTag, { value: 'Module' });
/******/            }
/******/            Object.defineProperty(exports, '__esModule', { value: true });
/******/        };
/******/    })();
/******/    
/************************************************************************/
var __webpack_exports__ = {};
/*!**********************!*\
    !*** ./src/index.ts ***!
    \**********************/
__webpack_require__.r(__webpack_exports__);
/* harmony export */ __webpack_require__.d(__webpack_exports__, {
/* harmony export */   index: () => (/* binding */ index)
/* harmony export */ });
function index() {
    console.log("Hello");
}

/******/ })()
;
//# sourceMappingURL=index.js.map


And finally the error when running page in browser
Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module './index.js' does not provide an export named 'index' (at (index):15:14)


What am I missing?
I would appreciate any help on this as I simply can't figure it out my self
